# Excel code to look for a specific text in a cell (from a list of possible texts) and populate another cell

Tags: vba

So I am populating a spreadsheet with a copy n paste of my banking transactions.  I want excel to populate a cell 10 to the left of it with that specific costs cost centre number.
Eg,  Petrol has a cost centre number of 10
I copy and paste my bank statement in, the sheet sees all the cells containing 'petrol' and populates the cell ten to the left with a 10

I do not want to do this with a formula, I want to put it in vba.
Can someone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you have tried to encode your idea yourself someone can help you overcome whatever obstacles you may find in your path. While you have not tried to solve your problem yourself you would be looking for a free coding service which you won't find here. Amend your question and post the code you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to copy a value ten cells to the left.

Cells(Row,Column).Value = Cells(Row,Column + 10).Value

To get the values for 'Row' and 'Column', you can use the find function to find the address for 'petrol' and all the other values that you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was after.  It will be looking for a to see if a word from a list exists on the page, and if it does, populate another cell with a predetermined numeric code for that word.  SO it looks, sees that the word 'petrol' is in row 5, then determines the numeric value I have attributed to 'petrol' and populates a cell ten to the left of where it initially found 'petrol'